# Is $(\neg p \lor (p \rightarrow q)) \rightarrow\neg p$ a Tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

According to the truth table, following is is a Tautology or not?
$(\neg p \lor (p \rightarrow q)) \rightarrow \neg p$

Comment: Have you tried drawing a truth table for it? Then you'll see the answer

Comment: The tex of the formula that the user wrote is "(~p \vee (p → q)) → ~p". I was wondering if he/she means "not p" for "~p"...

Comment: $(a \lor b) \to c$ (either $a$ or $b$ is sufficient for $c$) is equivalent to $(a \to c) \land (b \to c)$ ($a$ is sufficient for $c$, and $b$ is sufficient for $c$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
p&q& \overline p&(p → q)&\overline p ∨ (p → q))& \overline p ∨ (p → q)) →  \overline p\\
\hline
T&T&F&T&T&F\\
F&T&T&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&F&F&T\\
F&F&T&T&T&T\\
\end{array}
so it is not a tautology

Answer (score 0):

Hint: See $p = F $ and $q = T $.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a \to b \equiv \bar{a} \vee b$, you get:
$$(p \vee (p \to q)) \to p \equiv (p \vee \bar{p} \vee q) \to p \equiv q \to p$$
which, of course, is not a tautology.

Anyway, if the real question is about $(\bar{p} \vee (p \to q)) \to \bar{p}$, then:

$$(\bar{p} \vee (p \to q)) \to \bar{p} \equiv (\bar{p} \vee \bar{p} \vee q)) \to \bar{p} \equiv (\bar{p} \vee q) \to \bar{p} \equiv\\
\equiv \overline{(\bar{p} \vee q)} \vee \bar{p} \equiv (p \wedge \bar{q}) \vee \bar{p} \equiv \bar{q} \vee \bar{p},$$

which, again, is not a tautology.

Comment: the real question is: (~p v (p → q)) → ~p

Comment: "~p" is the same of $\bar{p}$

Answer (score -1):

The whole implication is false when $(p \vee (p \rightarrow q))$ is true and $p$ is false. In this case, $p \rightarrow q$ must be true. This happens if $q$ is true or false. So that is not a tautology.